# Return true if list is not empty

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to return true if a list is not empty?

```
def fun(x):
    return x != []
```

Given some function called `fun` where we pass in a list x. List could look like `[]` or `[1,3,4]`.

I want to return True if the list is not empty. Am I doing that in the most pythonic way?

The reason I ask is because when I do `return x is not None` instead of `return x != []` I get a different answer. I guess this is because empty list is not considered null?

Comment: [bool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool)

Comment: Just cast the list to bool. bool([1,2,3]) = True. bool([])  = False. Because you want True if empty, then do: not(bool(x)).

Comment: Either `bool(x)`, or just `x`. In most cases, you don't need an actual Boolean value.

Comment: *"empty list is not considered null"* - an empty list, or any list, `is not None`, no. The ideal implementation here will depend partly on what you expect to happen if `x` *isn't* a list.

Comment: That doesn't fit the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the list to see how many items are inside:

```
def fun(x):
    return len(x) > 0
```

Or you can cast `bool` to be more pythonic:

```
def fun(x):
    return bool(x)
```